# Devices with more than one endpoint id?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, robo3t

```
db.getCollection('endpoint').find({device:ObjectId("5641c5bc20db5a0")})
```

when I write the above question, I got two results.

```
ObjectId("56442943483f0ca")
ObjectId("59f83b7cadd73ad")
```

How do I find all devices with more than one endpoint?

Comment: Probably, you could try `$count` in the *aggregation pipeline*. [Here is the link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)

Comment: Unfortunately, '$count' does not work, my friend.